# Google Analytics API, how to format total visitor result as dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

Im working on a local application that uses Google Analytics V3 API. Im using ga:visitors to get number of visits and GaData property "TotalsForAllResults" to get all visitors. However TotalForAllResults is a dictionary that uses `  with key value pair "ga:visitors" and "number of visitors". This is what the debugger shows:
[image]

My problem is im uncertain how to format the dictionary in order to desplay the result with Console.WriteLine. If i run the application i can see the total number when debugging but if i runn "TotalForAllReason" with console rightline i get -  [image]

After modifying a bit it looks like this (Thx Papa:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in d.TotalsForAllResults) { Console.WriteLine("Antal Besök:" +" " + kvp.Value); } Console.WriteLine(d.TotalsForAllResults.Keys + " = " + d.TotalsForAllResults.Values); Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the output i get now:

[image]

Is Generic.List etc  indicating that there is more to show or why does this message appear?

Anny suggestions?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a keyvaluepair, you can do this. Hope the syntax is right.

```
Console.WriteLine(d.TotalForAllReason[0].Key + " = " + d.TotalForAllReason[0].Value);
```

If you have more than one record, you can do this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair kvp in d.TotalForAllReason) {
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + " = " + kvp.Value);
}
```